# Project error: Cannot find type definition file for 'cropperjs'

Tags: typescript, netbeans, angular5, cropperjs

So, at the top of nearly every .ts file, I see this:

[image: Cannot Find Cropperjs]

Cropper is installed in package.json

Cropper is installed in package.json as an @typings

Cropper is here in typings.d.ts

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}

declare module 'stompjs';
declare module 'sockjs-client';

declare module 'node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js' {
  import cropper from 'cropperjs';
  export default cropper;
}
```

Here's the same error in the first pic in typings.d.ts but on a COMMENT!

[image: Cannot Find Cropper on a "COMMENT" in typings.d.ts]
So, it's not breaking anything but Netbeans 8.2 reports this.  Could it be that Netbeans is "wrong" and that everything's ok?

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the TypeScript from the command line? If so, does the build complete? If the build completes from the command line, the there is probably something awry with your Netbeans setup.

Comment: Yes, I do, ng serve --aot --prod and there's no issues. I believe you are correct and it "is" a problem with netbeans not letting the error through because there's no error in the dev console when the app runs.  I'm using NB 8.2 but I have 9.0 and 10.0. Need to try on those platforms. I'm a member of the build group, NetCat and will pose this question to Geertan with Netbeans